# Is there a common way for updating two joined tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update two tables in Laravel. But I don't know if you can do this while using an associative array with the help of Object->update($associative-array);

I have made an update sequence in laravel which updates a user and a location in two separate tables with a foreign key in the user table. I tried to update both tables doing update statements with the objects of the tables. I tried this in the following way:

1. `$user->update($attributes);`
2. `$user->update($attributes); $location->update($attributes);`

But this will only update the user table and skips the location table. The $attributes array contains multiple column data of the table user and location. The array is in order of the first column from the user table to the last column of the location table.

But neither of those tries updated both the tables. They only update user and skips location. As far as I know, is that you can do it this way with an associative array if the array contains the column data in the same order of a table and Laravel does the rest. With only updating the user table it does work, But I want it to work with two tables in the way It works using the update function with the object.

**MySQL tables**

```
users:
   id
   firstname
   middlename
   lastname
   active
   email
   password
   phone
   mobile_work
   phone_work
   gender
   position_id
   settling_id
   location_id

locations:
   id
   street
   house_number
   addition
   zipcode
   city
   province
   country
```

```php
public function update(Request $request, User $user, Location $location)
{
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'firstname' => 'min:3|max:50',
        'middlename' => 'max:50',
        'lastname' => 'min:3|max:50',
        'active' => 'required',
        'email' => 'min:3|max:100',
        'gender' => '',
        'phone' => 'numeric|min:8',
        'mobile_work' => 'numeric|min:8',
        'phone_work' => 'numeric|min:8',
        'position_id' => '',
        'settling_id' => '',
        'location_id' => '',
        'street' => 'required|min:3',
        'house_number' => 'required|numeric',
        'addition' => '',
        'zipcode' => 'required|min:6|max:7',
        'city' => 'required|min:3',
        'province' => 'required|min:3',
        'country' => '',
    ]);

    $user->update($attributes);
}
```

If the way I'm trying to do it is impossible, I'd like to hear what the standard approach is in updating two tables within one update sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake to not include the locations function from the model User into the update sequence.

User model:

```
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Location::class, 'id', 'location_id');
    }
```

I fixed the problem by simply deviding the $attribute array to 2 arrays with their own table column data. I also made a second statement which calls the location function from the model and updates it accordingly.

```
  $user->locations()->update($locationAttributes);
  $user->update($attributes);
```

With $attributes only containing the user information and $locationAttributes only containing the location information.

$locations() refers to the row in the table locations. It knows which row to pick by taking the location_id from the selected user.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is not quite right. You should try to update the relation as well, and preferably first like

```
$location->update($locationAttributes);
$user->update($userAttributes);
```

By the way, it is not quite clear you want to update Location record or you want to associate a new Location to User. If it is latter then you can associate the Location to user like

```
$user->locations()->attach($locationId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I forgot to use the function locations() in the model User which refers to the row from location the user uses. Thanks to you I figured.